# Smart function calling not working in python, even though works in truffle dev environment

Tags: python, truffle-contract

I am trying to call an AddDeviceOwner function from python. Somehow it is not working as nothing returns, not even an error. I tried the same in the Truffle Dev console and it works. Can anyone share any idea what could be the reason?

```
contract SmartDeviceChain {
    uint32 public device_id = 0;        // Device ID
    uint32 public device_user_id = 0;   // Device User ID

    //Individual IoT device
    struct device {
        string modelNumber;
        string ipAddress;
        address deviceUserAddress;
    }

    mapping(uint32 => device) public devices;

    //A owner of multiple IoT devices - could be a location with a group of sensors, 
    //or a hospital with multiple monitoring devices
    struct device_owner {
        string ownerName;
        string deviceOwnerType;
        address deviceUserAddress;
    }
    mapping(uint32 => device_owner) public device_owners;

    function addDeviceOwner(string memory _pName, address _pAdd, string memory _pType) public returns (uint32){
        uint32 userId = device_user_id++;
        device_owners[userId].ownerName = _pName;
        device_owners[userId].deviceUserAddress = _pAdd;
        device_owners[userId].deviceOwnerType = _pType;

        return userId;
    }

    function getDeviceOwner(uint32 _pid) public view returns (string memory,address,string memory) {
        return (device_owners[_pid].ownerName,
                device_owners[_pid].deviceUserAddress,
                device_owners[_pid].deviceOwnerType);
    }
}
```

```
truffleFile = json.load(open('build/contracts/SmartDeviceChain.json'))

abi = truffleFile['abi']
bytecode = truffleFile['bytecode']
contract_address = "0xf41CE442B32aB612F354FdbD721Fc1bD680dA107"
print("abi is:**********")
print(abi)
print("bytecode is:**********")
print(bytecode)

me = w3.eth.accounts[0]
print(w3.eth.get_balance(me))

SmartDevice = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
SmartDevice.all_functions()
# Submit the transaction that deploys the contract
tx_hash = SmartDevice.constructor().transact({"from": me})

# Initiate the contract

device_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=abi)
print("Smart device contract initiated.")

print("Check device information")
confirmed = device_contract.functions.getConfirmation().call()
print (confirmed) //This worked ok

user_id1 = device_contract.functions.addDeviceOwner("OwnerA","0x297CA5dbA140a902223Ec88f0168b37b547f2006","Hospital").call()
#user_id1 = device_contract.functions.addDeviceOwner("OwnerA","0x297CA5dbA140a902223Ec88f0168b37b547f2006","Hospital").call()
#user_id2 = device_contract.functions.addDeviceOwner("OwnerB","0xA6797B11d2505649dbacbFbD5De315E560F96095","Hospital").call()
print("user_ids are: ", user_id1)
device_user = device_contract.functions.getDeviceOwner(1).call()
print(device_user)
```

Comment: Why do you use `.call()` with addDeviceOwner? Shouldn't it be `.transact()`?

Comment: Thanks, Ismael. I figured out the problem as you mentioned. I used transact() for the addDeviceOwner and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by changing to transact() for any modification functions.